# Adding content after add to cart button on woocommerce single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I have successfully added a content after short description on single product page with

```
if (!function_exists('my_content')) {
    function my_content( $content ) {
        $content .= '<div class="custom_content">Custom content!</div>';
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'my_content', 10, 2);
```

I saw that in `short-description.php` there was `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt )`

so I hooked to that.

In the same way, I'd like to add a content after the add to cart button, so I found `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' )`, and now I am hooking to `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`. I'm using

```
if (!function_exists('my_content_second')) {
    function my_content_second( $content ) {
        $content .= '<div class="second_content">Other content here!</div>';
        return $content;
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_content_second');
```

But nothing happens. Can I only hook to hooks inside `apply_filters`? From what I've understood so far by working with hooks is that you only need a hook name to hook to and that's it. The first one was a filter hook, so I used `add_filter`, and the second one is action hook so I should use `add_action`, and all should work. So why doesn't it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here, you need to echo content as it is add_action hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );
/*
 * Content below "Add to cart" Button.
 */
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

        // Echo content.
        echo '<div class="second_content">Other content here!</div>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is it specified anywhere that with action hooks you need to echo, and with filter to return the content? I never read anything about it :\

Comment: In add_filter, we need to return. If not then apply filter will not give value. But in case of do_action, if we echo in add_action callback function then do_action that value else empty value.

Comment: Check examples from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter and 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action this will help :)

Comment: Thanks, never noticed that :)

Comment: @wisdmlabs Please add underscore to function name. Otherwise it will cause fatal error.

Comment: underscore doesn't matter you gotta use a unique name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do **echo** instead of **return**.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'ybc_after_add_to_cart_btn' );
 
function ybc_after_add_to_cart_btn(){
    //add text OR HTML here 
    echo '<p>After custom text here</p>';
}
```

If you want the same thing [on the shop archive page](https://yourblogcoach.com/how-to-add-text-after-or-before-cart-button-in-woocommerce/) then you need to use the [`woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link/) filter to modify the add to cart button.

Answer (score 0):

When using 'Action Hook' adding the content(html) out of php would be easy.

```
if (!function_exists('my_content_second')) {
    function my_content_second( $content ) {
        ?>
        <div class="second_content">Other content here!</div>;
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_content_second');
```

If need to add dynamic content just echo that content using variables or add using some condition.

---

Filter hooks are useful to modify the existing content and needs a return statement (the modified)

Action hooks are mostly useful to add content.

Answer (score 0):

Code above is add same link on all product pages. Insert this in functions.php file for editing only single product page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_single_product_button_2', 20 );
function additional_single_product_button_2() {
    global $product;
    // Define your targeted product IDs in the array below 
    $targeted_product_ids = array( put product ID here );

    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
        
        $link = 'put your link here';
        $name = esc_html ( "button with external link", "woocommerce" ); // <== Here set button name 
        $class = 'button alt';
        $style = 'margin-left: 1em';
    
        // Output
        echo '<button type="button" style="' . $style . '" class="' . $class . '" onclick="window.open(\'' . $link . '\', \'_blank\')">' . $name . '</button>';
    }
}
```

If you want to have rules for additional other product pages with other links  you need change functions names.